# How do I create a bookmark to a specific Gmail message when reading Gmail inside Chrome running on macOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail, ventura, bookmarks

There are answers to my question on the Web, but they appear to be for people running Chrome on an OS other than macOS. Here is [one](https://www.groovypost.com/tips/bookmark-gmail-messages/).

The problem seems to be the URL in the address bar (is that the correct term?) in Chrome running on macOS does not include the suffix after this example URL, which is what I'm seeing: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox

The working examples have more information, i.e.: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#all/162...

Here are my specs:

```
MacBook Pro Apple M1 Max
Ventura 13.5
Chrome Version 116.0.5845.110 (Official Build) (arm64)
I am part of the Google Workspace Labs program.
```

I don't know if there is any version information for the Gmail application itself but as far as I know, I'm up to date because I hit refresh in my browser.

Thank you in advance for any help. I have reasons I'd like to continue to use Chrome to read my Gmail. This is the one functionality I would like to have but do not seem to be able to figure out.

Comment: Wow! I'm surprised no one has an answer to this. It is too bad Google does not have any decent support or I would call them to find out how to do this.

I will definitely put a solution here if I figure it out. :)

When I run into Googlies, I'll ask them if they know how to do this. Almost all of the top tech people use Macs, so someone probably knows.